# what is force application? What are its advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: db2

I have googled what the force application about database is but I haven't found satisfactory answer. What is force application? What are its advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: It kills open connections to the database.  Useful if you want to take an offline backup or do some other administration on the server.  "db2 force application all" will kill any connections to the database server.

Answer (score 5):

This was the first search result for me:

> ### FORCE APPLICATION command
>
> Forces local or remote users or applications off the system to allow for maintenance on a server.

Source: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001951.html).

You can start with reading the above manual page for more details.